# Regex - Remove all other texts except matching text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm using sublime text 2 editor. I would like to remove all other texts except the name tag value.

Here is an example

```
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="c_email">Email (required)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="c_email" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the above code I would like to keep only the name tag value. To match all name tags I use regex like this

```
name="(.+?)"
```

It matches all name tags. But when I replace it with `$1` it only replaces `name="c_email"` with `c_email`

Can someone help me to erase all other texts?

Thanks

Comment: To make sure I understand: you want to replace the `<div>` tag and all its children with the value of the `name` attribute in the `<input>` tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it like that:

```
find: [\s\S]*?name="(.+?)"[\s\S]*
replace: $1
```

if you want to limit deletion to your target div:

```
find: <div class="control-group"[\s\S]*?name="(.+?)"[\s\S]*?</div>\s*</div>
replace: $1
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. But it found only 1 match.

Comment: @Giri: normal, the first find/replace is for only one occurence (the first) and delete all the text file. Use the second that only delete the div with the `control-group` class

Comment: Ok thanks. When I use `[\s\S]*?name="(.+?)"[\s\S]*?` its working correctly.